# Custom UICollectionViewLayout never asks datasource for DecorationView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've modified the `RFQuiltLayout` to that I can use a headerview. In `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect` I add the attributes

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* att = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:RFQuiltHeader atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
[attributes addObject:att];
```

this is the method returning the layout attributes:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:
(NSString*)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:decorationViewKind withIndexPath:indexPath];
    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.collectionView.contentSize.width, 100);
    layoutAttributes.zIndex = -1;
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

and i register it in initialize

```
[self registerClass:[EditionGridHeaderView class] forDecorationViewOfKind:RFQuiltHeader];
```

The headerview loads fine, but the datasource is never asked for it, so I can't modify it's contents. I could of course hack this to get a pointer to the headerview, but 
`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` should be called to do this right. What am I doing wrong? (The cells are asked for in the datasource as they should)